# Extraer dos campos de una tabla SQL con JOIN en PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, phpmyadmin

El problema es el siguiente, quiero sacar 2 campos de una tabla.

Esta es la parte de la página que debe mostrar los resultados.

[image: https://image.prntscr.com/image/54b01f31bee04a3792d83498b360b5f8.png]

Acá el código de esa parte:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading text-center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i><h3>Actualizar estado de pedido</h3></div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead class="">
              <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">#</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Fecha</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Cliente</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Estado</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Banco</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Referencia</th>
                  <th class="text-center">opciones</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <?php
                $pedidoU=  ejecutarSQL::consultar("select * from venta");
                $upp=1;
                while($peU=mysql_fetch_array($pedidoU)){
                    echo '
                        <div id="update-pedido">
                          <form method="post" action="process/updatePedido.php" id="res-update-pedido-'.$upp.'">
                            <tr>
                                <td>'.$peU['NumPedido'].'<input type="hidden" name="num-pedido" value="'.$peU['NumPedido'].'"></td>
                                <td>'.$peU['Fecha'].'</td>
                                <td>';
                                    $conUs= ejecutarSQL::consultar("select * from cliente where NIT='".$peU['NIT']."'");
                                    while($UsP=mysql_fetch_array($conUs)){
                                        echo $UsP['Nombre'];
                                    }
                        echo   '</td>
                                <td>'.$peU['TotalPagar'].'</td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="pedido-status">';
                                        if($peU['Estado']=="Pendiente"){
                                           echo '<option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>'; 
                                           echo '<option value="Entregado">Entregado</option>'; 
                                        }
                                        if($peU['Estado']=="Entregado"){
                                           echo '<option value="Entregado">Entregado</option>';
                                           echo '<option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>'; 
                                        }

                        echo        '
                              <td>BANCO</td>
                              <td>REFERENCIA</td>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary button-UPPE" value="res-update-pedido-'.$upp.'">Actualizar</button>
                                    <div id="res-update-pedido-'.$upp.'" style="width: 100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        ';
                    $upp=$upp+1;
                }
              ?>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

Acá una imagen de las tablas y las relaciones

[image: Imagen de las tablas y las relaciones]

Hay que hacer ciertas modificaciones y de todas esa es la que más problemas me ha dado. No tengo idea, intenté haciéndolo con `inner join` pero siempre me arroja error de sintaxis o algún error de otro tipo.

Las consultas están en *AJAX*, no entiendo mucho eso.

Comment: Gracias @ArtEze por las correcciones soy nuevo en esto

Comment: No, gracias a vos, me divierte hacer las correcciones. Si nadie cometiera errores yo terminaría aburriéndome.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque sea un poco tarde, añado la respuesta por si sirve. Para conseguir los datos que quieres presentar necesitas hacer uniones entre las tablas usando las claves relacionales, según tu esquema esta sería la consulta para rellenar la tabla:

```
SELECT d.NumPedido, v.Fecha, v.TotalPagar, v.Estado, v.ref,
c.Nombre, p.banco, p.ref as referencia
FROM detalle d
INNER JOIN venta v ON v.NumPedido = d.NumPedido
INNER JOIN cliente c ON c.NIT = v.NIT
INNER JOIN pago p ON p.nit = C.NIT
```

Si quisieras sólo la tupla de un determinado pedido habría que añadir:

```
WHERE d.NumPedido = '".$numpedido."'
```

He cogido los valores ref de las dos tablas porque no sé a cuál corresponde el que quieres mostrar.

Sólo como consejo en caso de que esté en tu mano modificar las tablas, resulta un poco extraño unir el pago a la venta a través del cliente, lo lógico sería unir el pagos a ventas y ambas a clientes, ya que un cliente puede tener varias ventas, y cada venta al menos un pago. La estructura actual sólo adquiere sentido si los pagos corresponden a plazos o a un acumulado de distintas ventas, quizás sea el caso.